# how to get column data from database whose column name have space?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to fetch data from database but in database one column name is specified "image URL" so
i am getting error.after delete that column name from query than i got data.can any one help me how to get data of that column whose column name have space.

my query is

```
$res = mysqli_query( $con ,"select p_name,price,image URL,description from product where p_name REGEXP '$kws'");
```

when i am deleted image URL from that query i got result. 
i am use phpMyadmin.

i am also tried "image URL" but unexpected result come.

Comment: try this give alias to your column *`select p_name,price,'image URL' as image_url,description...`* in php after fetch `echo $result['image_url']`

Comment: Simple solution would be not to use spaces in column and schema names.

Comment: In MySQL the identifier quote is a [backtick](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: M Khalid Junid 'image URL' as image_URL not working

Comment: at the time creation of table sql accepted table name with space so there is any trick to getting data.

Comment: Thank You Mike Causer backtick is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just around it by backticks like that

```
 $res = mysqli_query( $con ,"select p_name,price,`image URL` as imgurl ,description from product where p_name REGEXP '$kws'");
```

note:

why not create that column like that `image_URL` or this `imageURL` or something to prevent from making spaces.

EDIT:
to fetch your columns just give an alias to that spaced column and fetch by that alias

Comment: you are completely right but sql accepted with space so there is any trick to fetch that data.       thank you :)

Comment: @user3141708 you can give an alias after that and fetch with the alias one look updated answer

Answer (score 0):

use backtick with column name

```
`image URL`

$res = mysqli_query( $con ,"select p_name,price,`image URL`,description from product where p_name REGEXP '$kws'");
```

Comment: {"1":["nokia 11","200","image URL","3deedferjnjknkebcxvjch"],"2":["nokia 4564","5000","image URL","gvbjhgvjhgbjhgb"],"3":["nokia","6526552","image URL","hhjkhkhbhh"],"4":["nokia 556","45653","image URL",""]} geting this result..means oclumn image URL data is not arrived

Comment: this json you need to parse jSON and you can get your result.

Comment: json_decode() function parse json and return you an object

Comment: i know this is json but actual result i am not getting result of "image URL" column is "image URL"